# New user wanting to learn how to use Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

So as a new user that is interested in using Tor, is it really as simple and just downloading the package and then using firefox like normal?

Answer (score 1):

For most normal use cases, downloading TBB and using it out of the box is sufficient, plus the non-technical behavioral change (learning how not to stand away from the crowd, how not to be easily track-able, and not to make mistakes that can lead to identify you).

The Tor project website has a [list of warnings](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#warning) that is useful, plus there's a good community ([eg.](http://tor.stackexchange.com)) that can help along the path.. Yyeah, for most cases, the Tor project is making a great effort to make Tor usable out of the box (keeping that in mind while [configuring NoScript](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBJavaScriptEnabled), for example)...

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't "use firefox like normal", what you do is download and install the Tor Browser Bundle and then start Tor Browser. (The Tor Browser is *based on* Firefox and so it looks similar, but it's not the normal Firefox you may already have installed on your system).